# I have concerns about the wiring in a friend’s new house that frankly none of us understand

Tags: electrical, switch

I have a few basic concerns about the electrical wiring in a friend’s house that have me concerned.  First, every electrical outlet I have seen in the house has three 12-2 nonmetallic cables in the box.  I would think that in general, if an outlet wasn’t switched, if it was in the middle of a branch circuit it would have two nonmetallic cables in the box and if it was at the end of the run, it would have one cable.  A third could be added if it was a switch leg on a middle-of-run outlet.  So that is something basic that I don’t understand.  Secondly, when my friend bought the house, each room had a switch at the door that switched a single outlet in one box in the room.  When he changed out the outlets and switches for aesthetic reasons, each outlet was wired in such a way that the switching didn’t work.  I believe each black was wired to the brass side, and each white was wired to the silver or neutral side of the outlet.  I came in to try to fix this in one room, and I thought I knew which outlet had been switched and I broke the tab on the hot side, pigtailed all the whites to the neutral side except the one white I had determined was actually a hot on the switch leg (power came into the outlet on one cable, not to the switch first), and connected this switch leg hot to the top outlet, and the pigtailed black into the lower outlet, so that the lower outlet would always be hot and the upper outlet would be switched.  However,  it did not work.  Both top and bottom outlets were always hot.  Then I noticed that all the four other outlets on this circuit were showing as being wired incorrectly, specifically as a hot-ground reverse.  I scratched my head, did a YouTube search, and discovered that this condition could be caused by a disconnected neutral in the circuit.  So I assumed that the white I was treating as a hot on the switch leg was actually a neutral, so I moved it from the upper outlet hot side to the neutral side and the hot-ground reverse indication went away on all the other four outlets.  Strangely, before I switched the neutral over, the outlet tester said the outlet I was working on was wired correctly, AND when I switched the white to the neutral side it also said that outlet was working correctly.  It gets stranger.  When I initially removed the outlet and separated all wires and the switch too, to see where power was coming in, I found the hot cable (the black in that cable) and I needed to know which of the other two cables was the switch leg, so I did a continuity check.  I found what I thought was the switch leg because the black wire had continuity between the switch and outlet, but initially I thought I had continuity on the white, but in subsequent tests I never got continuity on the white.  Then someone else came in and broke open all the outlets and found the one that was switched.  That outlet also had three nonmetallic cables in it.  I haven’t looked specifically at it, but as I said at the beginning, why would any middle-of-the-run outlet need any more than two cables if it wasn’t switched.  I don’t understand what’s going on here and it worries me that there could be a latent problem that could at the worst cause a fire.

Comment: Residential wiring can be a tree configuration. That wouldn't explain *all* the "3 cable" receptacles, but it could explain some - i.e., 1 in, 2 out to 2 different places. The only real way to figure that out is a full mapping: Turn off power, cap all 3 cables in one box, turn on power, see what doesn't work and identify which of the 3 is incoming power. Turn off power. Reconnect. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: I think a sketch of your findings and pictures of the open boxes would be helpful. Label your sketch with the picture numbers.

Comment: Stop working on it immediately. Get a textbook or two on home wiring and learn how homeruns, branches, and switch loops work. Disconnect all the wires in every junction box that you changed. Analyze all the outlet circuits starting from the service panel, until you know what is supposed to be connected to what. - If you can't develop the necessary analytical skills, or find a friend who has such skills, then you will have to call in a professional electrician.

Comment: Ruskes, power could come to the switch first, in which case the neutral would go straight through to the fixture, unless it was a smart switch that needed the neutral connected, or power could come to the fixture first in which case the switch leg has no neutral.  The situation I had was the latter.  I guess I didn’t explain that part well.  But why would I have continuity in the black on the switch leg but not the white?  It appears that what I thought was the switch leg wasn’t a switch leg at all, since someone else found the outlet that was switched.  Why continuity on the black then?

Comment: Paragraphs are your friends.  They help you communicate more effectively.

Comment: Simple question:  What initially raised your concerns and what problem were you trying to solve?

Comment: @SteveWellens Yes, I apologize for not breaking it up.  I should have actually broken it into more than one post

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson, The new owner originally had switched outlets in each room, but lost that functionality when he replaced all of the outlets for aesthetic reasons.  I was trying to get that functionality back.  But I noticed in looking at four or so outlets around the house that they each had 3 Romex cables in the box, which surprised me.  I jumped to the conclusion that they are all like that.  The first commenter pointed out that at least some of the outlets may have branches come off of them which could explain that, but it wouldn’t make sense to see it on all of them.

Comment: @Ruskes -- [non-metallic sheathed cable](https://www.amazon.com/Non-Metallic-Sheathed-Residential-Wire-Equivalent/dp/B07J9Q7WK3?th=1).

Comment: OP, you have a time-consuming and potentially dangerous mess on your hands. As noted, you (or a pro) need to take this apart and map everything. Once mapped, putting it back together safely is relatively straightforward. (You have a torque screwdriver, right?)

Comment: @GregBradley "*I apologize for not breaking it up. I should have actually broken it into more than one post*" Guess what, you still can! Use the [edit] to correct, rather than apologize and leave it as is. You need a blank line to get a paragraph on this platform. You can copy parts, cut them, and make new questions with them. Take the [tour] as well.

Answer (score 2):

If people have been repeatedly swapping wires over in an attempt to fix things, you can easily end up with a situation where you have no idea what goes where any more.  Attempting more swapping of wires is unlikely to solve it, and may leave the whole lot unsafe.

It sounds like there are several branches in the circuit, in addition to any wires running to switches.

The only real solution at this point is to trace all the wires.  You'll need either a signal generator and receiver, or a continuity tester.  If the wires are in cables (e.g. romex), you can identify the ends buy shorting one end of a cable run (e.g. with lever Wago blocks), then hunt around with the tester to find which other end has the wires shorted.  Take off all the accessories and trace every single one of the wires.  Label them.  Then wire it up correctly.

Comment: to be clear and safe: you are suggestion mapping it with the circuit "off" at the panel. Especially w.r.t. "shorting", you are connecting wires (e.g. black to white) from one cable, to create loops so you can identify that wire at its other end with a continuity tester. You don't mean "shorting" it to trigger the breaker. I know you know, my concern is with the reader.